KDevelop not finding easy C++ include file
I'm new to KDevelop.  I'm trying to build a C++ program that starts with
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
But it can't find it.
This header is located at
/usr/include
GCC is supposed to look at this directory for example:
jvonachen@pop-os:~$ g++ -print-prog-name=cc1plus -v
.../usr/include...
In project -> open configuration... -> Language Support -> Includes/Imports I added /usr/include/ to the list of includes, which I should not even need to do, right? GCC already naturally looks there. Yet I still get the error
/home/jvonachen/projects/VulkanTest/build> /usr/bin/ninja
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vulkantest.dir/main.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/vulkantest.dir/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++ -std=c++17 -O2 -O3 -DNDEBUG -MD -MT CMakeFiles/vulkantest.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/vulkantest.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/vulkantest.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/jvonachen/projects/VulkanTest/main.cpp /home/jvonachen/projects/VulkanTest/main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
2 | #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
*** Failure: Exit code 1 ***

The parser has no problem, no indication of a problem in the editor.  But the build fails.

[Edit] and post the errors as a code block, use the button <> on the editor toolbar. As you can see, formatting the code with surrounding ` and blank lines is not a good idea.

KDevelop uses the CMake buildsystem to compile C++. If you want to fix include problem, it's gonna be done at the C++ level, not the KDevelop parser for the editor.
To include glfw, simply add those two lines in the your CMakeLists.txt file:
find_package(glfw3 3.4 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(vulkantest PUBLIC glfw)

This will make CMake build correctly, with the right flags.
KDevelop should be picking up those flags by default for its intellisense

This did not help.  Error message:  By not providing "Findglfw3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3", but CMake did not find one.

@JohnVonachen since you have glfw installed using your system package manager, CMake should be able to find it. If not, report a bug to your linux distribution. On arch I had a similar problem, reported the bug and got it fixed. Also, using a proper C++ package manager like vcpkg makes such case work by default.

I have always used apt.  Vulkan I think is not well supported in Pop_OS! but is well supported in Ubuntu.  For instance I could not use the precompiled binaries provided by LunarG for the Vulkan SDK because they did not work on mine.  I had to download the tarball and build it locally.

@JohnVonachen if you don't want to use a package manager, I would suggest to build glfw yourself, then install it. Find package will work by default. Some linux distributions omit cmake metadata from package since distribution themselves used to use autotool for C packages. I would still suggest to report a bug to your distribution since find package is supposed to work when you install development files for a library.

I had used apt to install "sudo apt install libglfw3-dev" Used locate to find all things glfw3, among other things found: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Config.cmake", which contains, 'include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/glfw3Targets.cmake")'  I think this is what it was looking for, no?

@JohnVonachen if that file is present, then find_package should be working out of the box. The file glfw3Targets.cmake exists too?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I installed a 30 day free trial of CLion and was building within the hour.  Also there is lots of documentation of others having similar problems in the comment section of the Vulkan Tutorial.  I should have looked there first.  I didn't realize.  Don't give it a second thought.
